# How to get rid of rounding of Numbers while displaying an integer value in one decimal format e.g 5.3

Tags: xpages

I m working with Xpage . My control has some integer fields that are computed based on sum formula . when I display the value of that field the value gets rounded .e.g the orignal value was 13.9 but it shows as 14.0
How to get rid of rounding of Numbers while displaying an integer value in one decimal format e.g 5.3

Comment: Without seeing your source code it's difficult to say what's going on. Sum between ints returns int unless one of the numbers is decimal or cast as decimal and so is the result. Also, are you using converters?

Comment: Actually I am using data table . If I ignore the sum and just enter value e.g 13.92 and save it , the data table shows it as 14.0 . Converter is used to display value in 0.0 format

Comment: Do I miss something? You have integer field and want to show value of 13.9? Make it double then.

Comment: Again, if you post the source code it will be easier to understand